# How to click on all connect button in linkedin with python & selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

I made linked in connecting script but he is clicking on my class button now my error is how to click on all connect button?

how can I click on all connect button?

here is my code:

```
#search

click_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/header[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input[1]/input[1]"))).send_keys("pyt")
time.sleep(.2)
click_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/header[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input[1]/input[1]"))).send_keys("hon")
time.sleep(.2)
click_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/header[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated[1]/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input[1]/input[1]"))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
click_people = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/button[1]/span[1]"))).click()
click_connect = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/button[1]"))).click()
click_done = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]"))).click()
```

Comment: So... where is your error?

Comment: How can I click on all connect button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute XPath locators is not the best idea as it makes them very fragile and sensitive to any [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) change

The recommended [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) is using [ID](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) where possible, however when IDs are absent or dynamic it's better to come up with an alternative way.

For example you can stick to button text.

Compare your XPath expression for `People`:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[7]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/button[1]/span[1]
```

with this one:

```
//span[text()='People']
```

And both expressions are basically matching the same element:

[image]

So you can fetch all `Connect` buttons using [find_elements_by_xpath()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) function like:

```
connect_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='Connect']")

for connect_button in connect_buttons:
    print(connect_button.get_attribute("aria-label"))
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: error:         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\linked_conecting_script.py", line 93, in <module>
    for connect_button in connect_buttons:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: use `find_elements_by_xpath` function

Comment: still getting when he click on connect button and giving a traceback error

Comment: Bro Now How Can I click on the done button because when he click on connect button getting traceback error